# How do i add UITableView in the UITableView cell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I Have one tableview(First) in that i want another tableview(Second) in the cell of first tableView.
In short i want each cell contains one more tableview.

So help me out with this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think the below method is better this tutorial shows you how to create a tableView inside of another tableView http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

My Solution:
That approach is bound to run into serious problems, so I suggest scrapping it. If you have nested table views (or scroll views, more generally) then the scrolling behavior of the views will be erratic. A better solution is to use variable height table view cells: you just create the cell view to hold all the multiple choice options you need, and implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your table view delegate to supply the heights of the cells.

Comment: NO actually the need is that i wanted to add the TableView on each cell of parent TableView..